# How can I go about invoking a web service from within an MFC application? (VS 2008)

Tags: web-services, mfc, invoke

Could someone share their approach with me?

How did you manage to invoke a Web Service from and MFC application in VS2008?

I have an MFC application, and I would like to hook up with a third party's Web Service to facilitate the processing of medical claims.

I presume I will be able to locate the ATL Server source Code at CodePlex. And, I presume I will be able to identify the sproxy tool within it. But, can anyone offer me a few more details as to how to proceed further? Or could you refer me to any documentation I can chase through?

Is this the "correct" tehnique? Should I look into gSoap?

Many thanks for any assistance,

.......Cameron

Answer (score -1):

One way to add web service to a .net application is to right click the "Service Reference" in the solution explorer window.

WCF application can be added the same way.

Comment: Thanks Brandon, but my MFC application is not a .net application.